# Totcount depending on environment

Tags: counters, totcount

I'd like to have a counter, called `ProblemPoints` in the MWE, which is dependent on an environment `problem`, such that I can print the total points of each problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{ProblemPoints}

\newenvironment{problem}
{
\setcounter{ProblemPoints}{0}
Problem: (\total{ProblemPoints} points)
}
{\vspace{1cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}
Question 1: (2 points)\addtocounter{ProblemPoints}{2}
Question 2: (2 points)\addtocounter{ProblemPoints}{2}
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
Question 1: (5 points)\addtocounter{ProblemPoints}{5}
Question 2: (1 points)\addtocounter{ProblemPoints}{1}
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Here it just prints 6 (the total points of the last Problem) at each problem.

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of the `exam` document class? BTW, you set the counter to 0 whenever you start the environment.

Comment: I am now, thanks :) I'm still interested in a solution though, because I wanted to add this functionality to an already existing project which would require a lot of time to translate to the `exam` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\total` can only store one value. You can use the `\label`-`\ref` method.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcounter{problempoints}
\renewcommand{\theproblem}{\theproblempoints}
\newcounter{question}

\newenvironment{problem}
 {%
  \par\addvspace{1cm}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \setcounter{question}{0}%
  \setcounter{problempoints}{0}%
  Problem: (\ref{PB\arabic{problem}} points)\par
 }
 {%
  \addtocounter{problem}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{problem}\label{PB\arabic{problem}}%
  \par\addvspace{1cm}%
 }
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{question}%
  Question \thequestion: (#1 points)\addtocounter{problempoints}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}
\question{2} What is $1+2$?
\question{2} What is $1+3$?
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}
\question{5} What is $100\cdot 100$?
\question{1} What is $2^4-4^2$?
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Each problem steps a counter for getting a label expanding to the final value of `\theproblempoints`.

I do `\stepcounter` at the beginning, then step back the counter and do `\refstepcounter` again, in order to set the current label at the last minute, so you can also use `\label` inside the environment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I'm not quite sure why you need both `\newcounter{problem}`and `\newcounter{problempoints}`
if you are setting `\renewcommand{\theproblem}{\theproblempoints}`.

Comment: @G.Basso When LaTeX performs `\refstepcounter{problem}`, it sets the current label to the expansion of `\theproblem`; so `\label{whatever}` just after the `\refstepcounter` command will make `\ref{whatever}` issue that value of `\theproblem`. In this case `\label` takes its argument built from the current value of `problem`.